# Pointer arithmetics after cast

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following C++ pseudocode:

```
// Pointer to contiguous memory block suitably aligned to contain
// an array of type T. Possibly obtained via std::malloc or std::aligned_storage.
void *buffer = ...;
// Now cast as T pointer.
T *ptr = static_cast<T *>(buffer);
// Do some pointer arithmetics. For instance, construct the first two
// elements of the array.
::new (ptr) T();
::new (ptr + 1) T();
// etc.
```

Is this legal? What does the standard say about doing pointer arithmetics after a cast? 5.7/5 of the C++11 standard talks about arithmetics on pointers to elements of an array object, but **can any contiguous memory block be considered as an array**?

Comment: As long as `T` doesn't have extended alignment requirements this should be OK.

Comment: Why the need for `void*`? Use `std::aligned_storage` directly...

Comment: The type provided by aligned storage will be some kind of POD type won't it?

Comment: @Praetorian: I am assuming that buffer here points to some place already properly aligned for whatever T is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is legal.  In terms of arithmetic, `ptr + 1` is effectively the same as `((uint8)ptr) + (sizeof(*ptr)*1)` for any typed pointer.  So yes, given any typed pointer, the memory being pointed at can be treated as a contiguous array of elements of that pointer's type, and you can use type casts to change the behavior for any given pointer-arithmetic operation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the char cast... Just noted the footnote 81) in 5.7.

Comment: The standard defines `ptr + 1` as the address of the element that is offset by 1 from the element that `ptr` points to in the **same array** as the element that `ptr` points to (plus an exception for one-past-the-end pointers), not as some complicated jumble with `uint8` (§5.7/5).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: it does however mention conversion to character pointers: "Another way to approach pointer arithmetic is first to convert the pointer(s) to character pointer(s): In this scheme the
integral value of the expression added to or subtracted from the converted pointer is first multiplied by the size of the object
originally pointed to, and the resulting pointer is converted back to the original type." (5.7/6, footnote)

Comment: While it may be valid, it could also be cause undefined behavior if the buffer isn't correctly aligned for type T.  On some platforms it is a non-issue (most of x86) while on others (ARM) it can cause a hardware exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is legal. Pointer arithmetics don't really have anything to do with type casting. All there is in it is doing math on address using increments equal to size of the underlying types. Since these operations do not dereference a pointer (read/write memory pointed by that address), it is safe to use before object(s) initialization. And yes, you can refer to contiguous memory blocks as arrays.

Comment: Could you please dig out relevant quotes from the standard? I understand your comments on an implementation level, what I am trying to understand is how portable is the code (and on a tangential note, how to read and look for relevant parts in the standard).

Comment: Pointer arithmetics are defined in terms of arrays, not addresses (§5.7/5). In general the standard does not allow producing pointers that go beyond the bounds of existing array objects, even if not dereferenced (also in §5.7/5).

Comment: Can I assume then that the memory returned by malloc, and, more generally, raw storage blocks can be considered as arrays for the purpose of pointer arithmetics?

Comment: @bluescarni I don't know. I know the standard also says that for the purposes of `+` and `-` on pointers, any object can be treated as an array of a **single element**. I guess that means `ptr+1` is fine, but `ptr+2` isn't, but I'm not sure.